# Chrome not responding to flexbox css in my footer?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't figure out why Chrome is not responding to my footer flexbox css the website is www.batistaelectric.com it works on my Iphone chrome browser, safari Iphone browser, Imac safari browser it even works in my chrome preview from Brackets but not on Chrome after I upload it to the server.

On Chrome browser on Imac, the footer stays inline instead of stacking in a column.

```css
  @media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  .pv-header {
    width: 100%
  }
  .pv-footer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: - ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pv-footer">
  <div id="nav-a">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="button1">
          <b><a href="about.html">About Us</a></b>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="button1">
          <b><a href="Disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></b>

        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="button1">

          <b><a href="https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/13910995" class="iubenda-nostyle no-brand iubenda-embed" title="Privacy Policy ">Privacy Policy</a><script type="text/javascript">(function (w,d) {var loader = function () {var s = d.createElement("script"), tag = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.src="https://cdn.iubenda.com/iubenda.js"; tag.parentNode.insertBefore(s,tag);}; if(w.addEventListener){w.addEventListener("load", loader, false);}else if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent("onload", loader);}else{w.onload = loader;}})(window, document);</script></b>


        </div>


      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>


  <h3>Batista Residential Electric, INC.</h3>


</div>
```

This is a snapshot of how it looks on my chrome browser as you can see it's not wrapping when collapsed. So it's not seeing the flexbox css for the footer. 
[footer on chrome not stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnsNh.png) [footer not wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiHJM.png)

Comment: Please share your css code as well.

Comment: The footer stacks for me as expected (based upon your comment). But we need your CSS to see the styles being applied.

Comment: The css is below the html by scrolling. Is there another way I should do it that would be better?

Comment: the CSS has 3 x { and 2 x } either you have a missing } or didn't copy it. Not sure if that the issue given it stacks for me.

Comment: It seems to be stacking for most of you so that is good. I repeated the code in the main body of the css above the media screen size is that a mistake? It stacks in most of the browsers I try except Imac chrome.

Comment: Do you have <!DOCTYPE html> on first line of your HTML file?

Comment: have you putted these meta in the head?<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the "buttons" (li elements) in the .pv-footer div?
If so, you need to make their direct parent flex. In this case:

```
#nav-a ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Even then, if they are small enough to fit within the viewport width, then they still wont wrap. You would need to increase their width with something like this:

```
#nav-a ul li {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Making the .pv-footer flex allows it's direct descendants to flex, but not nested elements like the list items (li).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but I was talking about the Batista residential electric Inc  being next to the buttons on my IMac Chrome browser. But no one else seems to see it, I've checked on four different browsers including mobile Chrome and the only one haveing problems flexing is the Chrome on my IMac.

Comment: Did you get it figured out? If not, which version of MacOS are you running, and which version of Chrome?

I'm taking a look in Chrome 80 on MacOS Catalina and everything looks good.

And lastly, have you done a hard refresh of the browser to make sure it's not loading old versions of your css file(s)?